# Impossible to pass scope in http as data

Tags: angularjs

I want to pass my `$scope.data` as data in `$http-request`.
`$scope.data` is not empty!

```
$http({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: url,
    data: $scope.data
})...
```

But when sending this request the data is empty.

Comment: Are you sure it is not empty when you refer to it? Have you tried to `console.log` right before the `$http` request? Have you made sure the `$scope` is injected?

Answer (score 0):

Try this shortcut method

**From Angular docs** 
Look under the **Shortcut methods** section [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
$http.put(url, data, config)
 .then(
   function(response){
     // success callback
   }, 
   function(response){
     // failure callback
 });
```

Comment: It's still "no properties".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node.js make sure you have included body-parser module and access it by request.body

Comment: try sending as :-
   data : {abc:$scope.data}

Comment: Thanks!!!
This was my mistake! I don't know why but I defined my scope as array and not as object -.-

now
data:$scope.data
works